# ReactNative Android arrow function not showing data dynamically inside render

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am learning `React Native` and i am trying to display some dynamic data using for loop and arrow function.

I am facing issues exactly data is not showing on screen but inside log it is printing for loop data.

What is wrong in this code ? As i am only able to see `49` as a value in `console.warn`.

**Code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, View, Text, ScrollView, Platform, Alert } from 'react-native';

export default class MyApp extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  dynamicList = () => {
    
    var myloop = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      console.warn(i)
      myloop.push(
        <View key={i} style={styles.item}>
          <Text style={styles.item_text_style} onPress={() => { Alert.alert('Alert', `Title ${i.toString()}`) }}>Title {i}</Text>
          <View style={styles.item_separator} />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }



  render() {

    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View >
          <Text >Welcome to React Native!</Text>
          {this.dynamicList()}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create(
  {
    MainContainer:
    {
      flex: 1,
      paddingTop: 25
    },

    item_text_style:
    {
      fontSize: 20,
      color: '#000',
      padding: 10
    },

    item_separator:
    {
      height: 1,
      width: '100%',
      backgroundColor: '#263238',
    }
  });
```

Comment: Data is being added to the array, you can return the array or better use a map if you have an array

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan using map i am able to do that but why this code is not working after retuning an array onPress not showing correct value..

Comment: @JayRathodRJ in your ```dynamicList``` function you need to return the `myloop` so it can render the array content.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your function in componentDidMount() above render, like

```
componentDidMount(){

this.dynamicList()

}
```

Also, you are pushing your items in an array, so should use javasSript map method to display the key value pairs from an array

Answer (score 0):

Please update your `dynamicList` function to following

```
dynamicList = () => {
  var myloop = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    console.warn(i)
    myloop.push(
      <View key={i} style={styles.item}>
        <Text style={styles.item_text_style} onPress={() => { Alert.alert('Alert', `Title ${i.toString()}`) }}>Title {i}</Text>
        <View style={styles.item_separator} />
      </View>
    );
  }
  return myloop;
}
```

Comment: Yes but the alert showing wrong value while we do *onPress* .. i am returning myloop..

Comment: For me it's showing correct values, here is a quick snack https://snack.expo.io/@saachitech/e017d8

Comment: It is showing me Alert Title 50 each time on Android Emulator on any item click..

Comment: Do you have idea why this is happening on Android Emulator ?

Comment: Not sure, I tested it on my Android and Expo Emulator and it working great on both.